# What would be a good UI element to give user ability to enter arbitrary text, or one of several special values?

Tags: usability, gui-design

Specific example is that we have a form which allows searching of issue tickets. One of the fields we want to allow search on is the assignee, currently this is a simple textbox.

We also want to give the user the ability to find all tickets which are unassigned, or all tickets that are assigned.

Have considered an autocomplete hint if the user starts entering the word unassigned, and to give a hint as "unassigned()", and "assigned()", if user starts entering the word assigned.

thoughts?

Comment: I always found advance search of Jira by Atlassian as one of the best. You can register for free and get insight. Here is a video demonstrating the same: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XK4zj5HcUx4

Answer (score 1):

I've always been amazed by search bars with built-in filters, like the Discord search bar.

By default, the search bar will help you search for specific words in all messages, but with the built-in filter options you can search for words or all messages (if left empty) *from* specific members, *in* specific channels, *with* specific criteria. In this case, in the example below, from a specific user, in the channel "Tips-and-tricks, and only those messages that contain an image.

In your case, you would probably want to search for `[assigned:no]`, and or even `[assignee:<name>]`, etc.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you can build a textfield and a single-select into one component and it still is usable.

Have you had a look at Jira? They have a basic search with dropdowns and an advanced search with "code". Sounds exactly like your use case.

[image: basic and advanced search in Jira]

Comment: I've looked at Jira, and we want to stay away from SQL style queries for our users. I was considering a combobox for the assignee, with defaults of Any() and None()

Answer (score 0):

GitLab has such an issue filter, maybe this approach would work for you as well?
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues?sort=created_date&state=opened